# Different between BoxConstraints.tight and fixedSized property in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, layout

I just ran through Flutter Docs on how to use `BoxConstraints` to impose constraint to widgets, and here is what the docs said about `BoxConstraints.tight`:

> Creates box constraints that is respected only by the given size.

So if I am not wrong, it behaves equally to what the `fixedSize` property would do, or same as assigning fixed value to `width` and `height` for a `Container` widget

So what is the key difference that make Flutter even deliver a separate version of constraint `tight`

I have tried to apply both of which to a `Container`, for me they are same

Comment: Isn't the `fixedSize` property only available in `ButtonStyle` and `MenuStyle`

Comment: If you ask, then yes. But I mean in what case that we should favor `BoxConstraint.tight` instead of pure `width` and `height` property